# How can I use concatenation within a request.POST.get() function? (django/python)

Tags: python, django

I was trying to iterate  `request.POST.get()` to get some inputs from my view's corresponding html file using concatenation.

However, no matter whether the input is filled, it always says that the input returns the fallback. (As in the default response that the programmer gives.)

Does anyone know how to solve this? I'm trying to make it so it adds each choice to the set of choices for each question.

**create.html**

```html
{% extends "polls/base.html" %}

{% block title %}Create a Poll{% endblock title %}
{% block header %}Create:{% endblock header %}

{% load custom_tags %}

{% block content %}
{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'polls:create' %}" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}

    {% for field in questionfields %}

    {% if field == 'question_text'  %}

    <label for="{{ field }}">{{ field|capfirst|replace }}:</label>
    <input type="text" name="{{ field }}" id="{{ field }}">
    <br>

    {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}

    <br>

    {% for choice in choicenumber|rangeof %}
    <br>
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">Choice {{ forloop.counter }}</label>
    <input type="text" name="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">
    <br>

    {% endfor %}

    <br>
    <br>
     <input type="submit" value="Create" name="submit">

</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

**views.py**

```py
def create(request):
    choicenumber = 3
    context = {
        'questionfields': Question.__dict__,
        'choicenumber': choicenumber,
    }
    submitbutton = request.POST.get('submit', False)

    if submitbutton:
        new_question = Question.objects.create(question_text=request.POST.get('question_text', ''), pub_date=timezone.now())
        if new_question.question_text == '':
            context = {
                'questionfields': Question.__dict__,
                'error_message': "No poll question entered.",
                'choicenumber': choicenumber,
            }
            del new_question
            return render(request, 'polls/create.html', context)
        else:
            new_question.save()
            for i in range(choicenumber):
                choice = request.POST.get(('choice' + str(i)), '')
                new_question.choice_set.add(choice)
                new_question.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(new_question.id,)))
    else:
        return render(request, 'polls/create.html', context)
```

> The error: TypeError at /polls/create/
> 'Choice' instance expected, got ''

> Request Method:    POST

> Request URL:   http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/create/

> Django Version:    3.0.8

> Exception Type:    TypeError

> Exception Value:   'Choice' instance expected, got ''

The error was in line 52 of the file:

> new_question.choice_set.add(choice)

---

I would be really thankful if anyone could help.

EDIT::

The models as requested:

**models.py**

```py
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        return now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.pub_date <= now
    was_published_recently.boolean = True
    was_published_recently.admin_order_field = 'pub_date'
    was_published_recently.short_description = 'Published recently?'


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

Comment: can you provide a `choice` model?

Comment: I added the models :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then else part should be like this:

```
else:
    new_question.save(commit=False)
    for i in range(choicenumber):
        choice = request.POST.get('choice' + str(i), '')
        if choice:
            choice_obj = Choice.objects.create(question=new_question,choice_text=choice)
            new_question.choice_set.add(choice_obj)
    new_question.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(new_question.id,)))
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked, but instead of using a commit=False on the initial save function I just removed it. (Apparently commit is not a given argument in Model save functions, only ModelForm save functions. Once again, thank you!

Comment: You are Welcome.